# What would be a complete way to check for null cross browser

Tags: javascript, null, cross-browser

I'm looping through an array in JavaScript to check for null in each object using jQuery, what would be the best cross browser solution for this?

Comment: jQuery has made it so easy to use that many developers are forgetting what Javascript is or solutions that can be solved easily w/o jQuery https://twitter.com/thephpdeveloper/status/18499858897

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`null` is pretty reliably `null`. If you don't care *specifically* about `null` - that is, if you'd do the same thing when something is `undefined` as you would when it's `null` or any other "falsy" value, you can just use

```
if (!array[i]) { /* nothing there */ }
```

However that's not safe if you're data is numeric, because zero is "falsy", or if they're strings where an empty string should *not* count as "empty" in the array, for the same reason. Thus you can compare with the double-equals comparator to `null`

```
if (array[i] == null) { /* nothing there */ }
```

I've never heard of any cross-browser issues with this.

Comment: this headed me to the right direction.. the problem I had was doing $(arrayname).each, instead of $.each(arrayname, function()).... doing the later worked for IE, FF.

Comment: Yes that'd certainly be a problem :-)

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with this:

```
if (myValue === null)
{
    \\ Null
}
```

Null is a reserved keyword in JavaScript, and it shouldn't change across browsers.

Comment: Trick there is that "undefined" is not `===` to `null`. If there are "holes" in an array because nothing's ever put *anything* there, then a reference to that element will be `undefined`, not `null`.

Comment: He asked for a test against null. Not null and undefined.

Comment: True, @SimpleCoder, he did, but if you're checking an array for empty cells there's a chance that the distinction would be important.

Comment: True, but then he wouldn't just be checking for null ;)

Comment: Well the real point is that `==` instead of `===` will work for both `undefined` and `null`.

Answer (score 0):

`(obj == null)` is pretty damn cross browser last time I checked.